Confusion about induction proof in recursion theorem
While reading Analysis 1 by Amann and Escher, I stumbled across the proof of the recursion theorem:

Let $X$ be a nonempty set and $a \in X.$ Furthermore, we assume, that for each  $n \in \mathbb{N}$ there is a function $V_n: X^n \to X$. Then there exist a unique function $f: \mathbb{N} \to X$ such that $f(0)=a$ and $f(n+1)=V_{n+1}(f(0),\dots,f(n))$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

The existence part of the proof relies on an induction where they prove the existence of functions $f_n: \{0,\dots,n\} \to X$


My problem with this induction proof is the following: Normally we have a for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$ a statement $A(n)$ that we wan't to prove by induction. Here each statement $A(n)$ isn't independent of $A(m)$ with $n \neq m$. We somehow choose simultanously. I hope it's clear what confuses me.

If I understand, your concern is that if $A(n)$ is the proposition "there exists a function $f_n$ such that (... statements involving $f_k$ with $k < n$ ...)", then even being able to state $A(n)$ assumes the construction of $f_k$ based on the truth of $A(k)$ for $k < n$?

Here's a way to think about (or revise?) the argument:
While it's not emphasized by the authors in the excerpt you provided, note that there's at most one function $f_n:\{0,\ldots,n\}\to X$ satisfying the first and third conditions listed, which I'll write here together as:
$$\begin{align*}
f_n(0)&=a\\
f_n(k+1)&=V_{k+1}(\,f_n(0),\ldots,f_n(k)\,)\qquad(0\le k<n)
\end{align*}\tag{1}$$
Indeed if $g,h:\{0,\ldots,n\}\to X$ both satisfy (1), then it follows by (strong) induction on $k$ that $g(k)=h(k)$ for all $0\le k\le n$, so $g=h$.
It's possible to prove there's at least one $f_n$ satisfying the conditions in (1) by induction on $n$ in essentially the same way the authors have, by setting $f_0=\{(0,a)\}$ and, given $f_n$ satisfying (1), defining
$$f_{n+1}=f_n\cup\bigl\{\,(\,n+1,V_{n+1}(\,f_n(0),\ldots,f_n(n)\,)\,)\,\bigr\}\tag{2}$$
and showing that it also satisfies (1) for $n+1$. Note this makes no reference to $f_k$ for $k<n$.
After this is done, we can observe that for all $k$ and $n$ with $0\le k\le n$, $f_k\subseteq f_n$ -- that is, the (unique!) function $f_k$ is extended by the (unique!) function $f_n$. This is proved by induction on $n$, with the induction step following from the definition in (2). This extension property corresponds to the second condition listed by the authors.

Thanks, thats answers perfectly my question.

The reason the first paragraph is unsatisfying is that it sweeps the problem under the rug by introducing yet another induction (we are now proving that for every $m$, for every $n \leq m$, for every $k \leq n$, there is an element $f_n(k) \in X$), which begs the question again: how do we know that the sequence of functions $(f_n){0 \leq n < m}$ agrees with the sequence $(f_n){0 \leq n < m+1}$ on the first $m$ entries? I think the correct way to analyse it is indeed to prove post hoc that the sequence of functions we just constructed satisfies the required properties.

@NaïmFavier Thanks for your comment but I don't understand your concern. In the case of a sequence $(f_0,\ldots,f_{m-1})$, the induction hypothesis would include that $f_n:{0,\ldots,n}\to X$ for all $0\le n<m$, so in particular $f_n(k)\in X$ for all $0\le k\le n$, and this property is preserved by the induction step when adding $f_m$. Similarly we may assume an extension property in the induction hypothesis, and it is preserved in the induction step.

If you assume an extension property in the induction hypothesis then we are back to square one: how can the claim $A(n)$ that we are proving by induction refer to another $A(k)$? Should we instead say that we are constructing a sequence of sequences of functions? This can keep going ad infinitum. In short, I am claiming that we don't gain anything by constructing a sequence of functions instead of just a sequence of values.

@NaïmFavier We don't need $A(n)$ to "refer" to $A(k)$ for $k<n$ if we're thinking of $A(n)$ as describing a property of a sequence as a whole. Very roughly, $A(n)$ says "there is a sequence of length $n$ whose $i$-th element is a function ${0,\ldots,i}\to X$ whose values satisfy the recursion relationship and such that the functions extend each other". Given that $A(n)$ is true, we extend the sequence by adding a new function which ensures $A(n+1)$ is true.

In order to extract the final function $f$ from this, you also need to know that the sequence you get from $A(n+1)$ extends the sequence you get from $A(n)$.

@NaïmFavier On your last point, I was originally thinking "that's immediate from the induction step", but reflecting on it more I agree with you that while I think this approach might help us avoid an issue expressing the induction predicate in (b), we still have a complication in (c) -- namely, in (c) what does "$f_n$" refer to? Intuitively we might think "the $n$-th function in the sequence from $A(n)$", but what's that if we haven't yet established uniqueness? I'll delete the first paragraph since it's not sufficiently helpful. Thanks for the discussion!
